# Message queue: msgsnd failed : Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

Can anyone please help me to point out as what is the error in my program?

Thanks in advance,
kingsmasher1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;     /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[15];  /* message data */
} msgbuf;

int main() {
    key_t key;
    int msqid, pid, length;
    msgbuf buf;

    msqid=msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT);

    if(msqid==-1){
        perror("msgget failed");
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("msgget succeeded. ID:%u",msqid);
    }

    pid=fork();

    if(pid==-1) {
        perror("fork failed\n");
    }

    buf.mtype=1;
    strcpy(buf.mtext, "This is a test message");
    length=sizeof(buf.mtext);

    if(msgsnd(msqid,&buf,length,0)!=0) {
        perror("msgsnd failed:\n");
    }
    else {
       printf("msgsnd succeeded\n");
    }
}
```

Output:
    msgsnd failed: Invalid argument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not have enough space in your `buf.mtext` (15 characters) for `"This is a test message"` (23 characters plust one more for a NUL terminator).

I'd say there's a good chance that may be corrupting your type or even some *other* piece of information on the stack (like `msqid` or `length` or `key`).

Whether that's the actual problem or not, it's still undefined behaviour and should be fixed. The first thing I'd do is check by replacing:

```
strcpy(buf.mtext, "This is a test message");
```

with:

```
strcpy(buf.mtext, "XYZZY");  // 5 plus the NUL
```

to see if it fixes it.

Alternatively, make `mtext` big enough to store the data you're putting in there.